# List all variables loaded by 'require' function

Tags: perl, require

I have a config file with bunch of data structures (arrays, hashes) and I load them into my perl script using

`require '<config>';`

I can use the variables from config that I know of but is there a way that I can list all the variables loaded by the require function? Ideally I would want them to load into a hash variable and refer them to avoid variable name conflicts

Answer (score 3):

Not easily, and this is why relying on global named variables is problematic. Instead, have your config file return a single data structure (like a hashref, so you can name parts of it) and load it with [do](https://perldoc.pl/functions/do) into a lexical variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = '/path/to/foo.conf';
my $data = do $file;
die "Failed to parse $file: $@" if !defined $data and $@;
die "Failed to read $file: $!" if !defined $data;
```

Make sure either to pass an absolute path to the file (recommended, to avoid depending on what your current working directory happens to be) or prepend a relative path with `./`, otherwise `do` (and `require`) will search `@INC` for the file, which since Perl 5.26 does not contain the current working directory. See [Path::This](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::This) for a way to get an absolute path relative to the current file.

Comment: Do you mean having the config file setup entirely as a hashref and gather all contents inside that? I'm also exploring the option of converting the config file as a package on the fly but I would prefer to directly load and be able to work with just the config

Comment: Yes, since the last statement evaluated is returned from the file, the file can just be a hashref. This is common in e.g. [Mojolicious config files](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::Config).